# Two OPENJSON, return each array element in separate rows

Tags: sql-server, join, json, cross-apply

I have a table where I save in JSON format the quantity that exit and return of a product.
The data saved in the two columns `out_quantity` and `in_quantity` is in array format.

```sql
CREATE TABLE products_info (
  product_id int NOT NULL,
  out_quantity varchar(4000) DEFAULT '[]',
  in_quantity varchar(4000) DEFAULT '[]'
 );
```

| product_id | out_quantity | in_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '[{"date":"2022-03-01","quantity":10}, {"date":"2022-03-02","quantity":20}]' | '[{"date":"2022-03-15","quantity":30}]' |

Using this query

```sql
SELECT product_id, o.out_date, o.out_quantity, i.in_date, i.in_quantity FROM products_info
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (
      out_quantity
  ) WITH (
      out_date date '$.date',
      out_quantity int '$.quantity'
  ) o
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (
      in_quantity
  ) WITH (
      in_date date '$.date',
      in_quantity int '$.quantity'
  ) i;
```

This is what I get

| product_id | out_date | out_quantity | in_date | in_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | 10 | 2022-03-15 | 30 |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | 20 | 2022-03-15 | 30 |

But what I'm trying to achieve is not to have duplicated data like this

| product_id | out_date | out_quantity | in_date | in_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | 2022-03-15 | 30 |

I know this is expected behaviour using cross apply but I couldn't find any other solutions.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=464d87fbd2f496baf0fc68ffcc6ec788)

I have also other columns that I get from JOINs like `product_description` that I get from table `products`. I haven't added them in this example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with only a single scan of the main table.

```sql
SELECT pi.product_id, o.*
FROM products_info pi
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT o.out_date, o.out_quantity, NULL in_date, NULL in_quantity
    FROM OPENJSON (
          pi.out_quantity
      ) WITH (
          out_date date '$.date',
          out_quantity int '$.quantity'
    ) o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, o.in_date, o.in_quantity
    FROM OPENJSON (
          pi.in_quantity
      ) WITH (
          in_date date '$.date',
          in_quantity int '$.quantity'
    ) o
) o;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see separate row per in and out then use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT product_id, o.out_date date, o.out_quantity quantity, 'out' As Direction
FROM products_info
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (
      out_quantity
  ) WITH (
      out_date date '$.date',
      out_quantity int '$.quantity'
  ) o
  Union ALl
  SELECT product_id, o.in_date, o.in_quantity, 'in'
FROM products_info
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (
      in_quantity
  ) WITH (
      in_date date '$.date',
      in_quantity int '$.quantity'
  ) o
```